# Redefine caption to accept title in bold or italics

Tags: floats, captions

Is there a way to give the `caption` command the option to display a small title in bold or italics before the caption main text? For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{SOME BOLD TITLE. Some text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I was thinking in redefining the command to accept something like `\caption{SOME BOLD TITLE}{Some text}`

Comment: I think, you will find ways with the `caption` package ;-)

Comment: Is `\caption{\textbf{SOME BOLD TITLE.} Some text}` a solution?

Comment: I already use that solution. I just want to avoid the `\textbf` on every caption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the `caption` command.
Because of `[#1]` "SOME BOLD TITLE" will also be used for the list of figures (instead of the hole figure-description).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\let\oldcaption\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[2]{
    \oldcaption[#1]{\textbf{#1:} #2}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{SOME BOLD TITLE}{Some text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]